# Identifying multiple STOMP endpoints in message controller

Tags: spring, spring-boot, websocket, spring-websocket, stomp

Is it possible to route different STOMP endpoints for each `@MessageMapping`?

For example, if I set my `WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer` like this:

```
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
@Configuration
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/ep1", "/ep2").setAllowedOriginPatterns("*").withSockJS();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
    }
}
```

Then, how can I specify `/ep1` & `/ep2` for each `@MessageMapping` in my controller?